# XAML build and job-specific OAuth token

Tags: azure-devops

We are in process of converting our XAML builds to build vNext (Build 2.0) on Visual Studio Team Services. As an intermediate step, I need to call Build 2.0 API from XAML build. In order to do that, I need access to authentication token (so called "job-specific OAuth token"). How do I do that?

Comment: It has been a while, but I still hope to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

XAML build predates OAuth and doesn't use OAuth access tokens (at least not as far as I know). As a result, you'll need to either script out [retrieving an OAuth token](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/Authentication/oauth) or just use a [Personal Access Token](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/authentication/pats).

Comment: If XAML build does not use OAuth access token, how does it authenticate against Visual Studio Team Services?

Comment: @AlexI No clue, it's been ages since I set up a XAML build controller. Even if it is authenticating using OAuth, it does not make the token available to the end-user. Keep in mind, XAML build hasn't received any significant updates in 3 or 4 years, and it was designed first and foremost for on-prem instances of TFS.